# Grab Text from a URL Using HTML?

Tags: php, html

I run my own game, and I can use PHP to get an updated value of how many users are online at a current time. I want to create an updating string of text that shows how many users are online. In game it's programmed to update the value every 20 seconds.

The problem is that my website can only use HTML, and that's about as far as it goes for how much customization I have. The other option is Flash, which I have zero clue on how to use.

The HTML doesn't seem to work with PHP inside of it, so I'm really unsure of how to approach this.

I just need the html to grab the text that outputs from a PHP url from my website, basically in the same way you use html to grab an image. It's 100% readable, and it's just a single string that I need to grab to show how many users are online. : ( Is there any way to do this or am I out of luck?

Comment: If you can use php why not send something like json as answer? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `<iframe src="#url"></iframe>` or `<embed src="#url"></embed>` if you want this to be done using only html.

Comment: YES! Thank you that is exactly what I needed!